# How to fix WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) function

Tags: php, hook-woocommerce

In php_errorlog file i get the message
**The WC_Cart::get_remove_url function is deprecated since version 3.3. Replace with wc_get_cart_remove_url.**

I have below function added

```
function lp_woocommerce_checkout_remove_item( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( is_checkout() || is_cart() ) {
        $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

        $remove_link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">×</a>',
            esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
            __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
            esc_attr( $product_id ),
            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
        ), $cart_item_key );

        return '<span>' . $remove_link . '</span> <span>' . $product_name . '</span>';
    }

    return $product_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'lp_woocommerce_checkout_remove_item', 10, 3 );
```

I replaced **WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key )** with **WC()->cart->wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key )**

Frontend start showing Fatal Error.

Comment: I believe the `wc_cart_remove_url` is a standalone function, so you can remove the `WC()->cart->` part. For reference i checked it here: https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_get_cart_remove_url

Comment: @Seregmir i did replace it like 
```
esc_url( WC()->cart->wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
```

but getting fatal error